# Xfig installed by homebrew: segmentation fault

Tags: homebrew

Surprisingly, I found that there is a [homebrew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/xfig) for `xfig`; I then installed `xfig` by:

```
brew install xfig
```

But, I cannot start `xfig`:

```
~$ xfig
Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C
Warning: X locale modifiers not supported, using default
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-times-medium-r-normal--16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*,-*-*-medium-r-normal--16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*,*--16-*" to type FontSet
Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset
Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset
[1]    70074 segmentation fault  xfig
```

What is going wrong? I am using MacOS Sonoma 14.1, Apple Silicon, and XQuartz is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been reported in Homebrew issue [Segmentation fault when executing xfig on apple silicon #160515](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/160515). It appears the issue needs to be fixed with the formula itself (or its fontconfig dependency formula).